# C# referencing a methods variables from another method

Tags: c#, methods, reference

Sometimes it happens that I want to use a lot of Method As variables in Method B.
Usually its quite a pain to pass all the variables to this method, especially if I have to do this a lot of times (but cannot simply copy paste, because some things change) or am just to lazy.

Is there such a thing like a "inner Method"? Or some concept to handle this in an easy way?

What I want to do:

```
    public void A()
    {
        int a = 4;
        string b = "Hello World";

        B(ref vals);

        //Or like so
        C(ref current);
    }

    public void B(ref AllValues)
    {
        a = 3;
        ...
    }

    public void C(ref MethodThatSharesAllValues method)
    {
        method.a = 3;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Not currently possible, you need to pass the values around. C# 7 will have local functions though.

Comment: create an object that encapsulates all the fields you need passed around.  Pass that object around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## If they all are in the same class

You can configure them as class variables:

```
public class MyClass{

    //set this as private/protected/public or nothing and you can also set a default value
    int a;

    public void A()
    {
        a = 4;
        string b = "Hello World";

        B();

        C();
    }

    public void B()
    {
        a = 3;
        ...
    }

    public void C()
    {
        a = 3;
        ...
    }
}
```

---

## Elseway

```
public static class MyClassA{
  public static int a = 0;
  
  public static void MethodA(){
    this.a = 3;
  }
}
```

now from method B you can access MyClassA

```
int myExValueA = MyClassA.a;
```

---

Elseway you gotta pass them as parameters

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. Of course that's the best way to do it. Hadn't thought about that at all, don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class which will hold your parameters and then pass only an instance of this class

```
public void metA(Parameters input)
{
    input.a = 5;
    input.c = "hello";
    metB(input);
}

public void metB(Parameters input)
{
    input.b = 10;
}

public class Parameters
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public string c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the variables static in a class header and use them as you like, private if are in the same class, protected for child classes, internal or public else. Or box the variables in a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

If passed variables are the same type you can use data structure like int[] or string[] or List<int> or List<string> and pass them without ref but this has the disadvantage that more than often you would not use all varibales from the structure as it is also the case with the class boxing variant.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following:

```
public void foo() {
    int a = 10;
    // ...
}

public void foo_bar() {
    // "a" is not in scope for foo_bar, so this won't compile
    a = 20;
    // ...
}
```

would definitely be invalid. I don't think that this was what you were driving at in your question though.

You can do something *somewhat* similar to what you ask for using [closures](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained) but they're a bit tricky to work with. Basically, something like this would be valid (and I'm not sitting in front of an IDE so forgive me if the syntax is a little off):

```
Func<int> GetCounter() {
     int count = 0;

     // This will capture the count variable from its context
     Func<int> method = () => ++count;

     return method;
}
```

While a fair number of languages (including some versions of C++ now I guess) have closures (or some similar variant), there seems to be little consistency in exactly how they work across languages (e.g. on whether the "count" variable should be immutable once it's captured) so it's important to check the documentation for the language you're using (in this case, C#) to understand exactly how they work.

In terms of the first code sample I provide, I doubt that that's what you were asking about, but just as a brief digression you probably wouldn't really want it to be the allowable anyway (and again I suspect that this isn't the syntax/semantics you're asking about) as it would quickly lead to unexpected/undefined behavior. For example:

- If you have a local variable `a` that's initialized in `Foo()` and you refer to it in `Foo_Bar()` before you run `Foo()`, what should its value be?
- If you run Foo() to initialize the variable, edit the variable in Foo_Bar(), and then run Foo() again, should you re-initialize the variable or allow it to remain what Foo_Bar() set it to?
- Is it safe to garbage collect a local variable after the method call completes, or might it be referred to again?

See the following:

```
public class SomeObject
{
   public int SomeProperty { get; set; } = 6;
   // ...
}

public class SomeOtherObject
{
   // ..
}

void foo() {
    // What is the content of "a" before foo() runs?
    object a = new SomeObject();

    // Which "a" should this refer to - the one in foo() or the one in foo_bar()?
    // Also, is this a valid cast given that we haven't specified that SomeOtherObject can be cast to SomeObject?
    var b = (SomeObject)a;

    // If we run foo() again, should "b" retain the value of SetProperty or set it back to the initial value (6)?
    b.SetProperty = 10;

    // ...

    // Is it safe to garbage collect "a" at this point (or will foo_bar refer to it)?
}

void foo_bar() {
    object a = new SomeOtherObject();
    // ...
 }
```